# libwnck how to find the icon path of an application/window

Tags: python, gtk

I get the list of windows with libwnck in python. But I don't manage to get the icon path of the application.

```
import wnck

screenW = wnck.screen_get_default();
screenW.force_update()

windows = screenW.get_windows()
  list = []
  for window in windows:
    print 'icon name: ' + window.get_application().get_icon_name()
```

get_icon_name return me the name/title of the window and not the icon name.

For example chrome icon is:
    /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/google-chrome.png

How could I get this path?

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libwnck/tree/libwnck/application.c#n291) of libwnck shows that the function is not really implemented right now (and only returns the name of the application as you already wrote):

```
const char*
wnck_application_get_icon_name (WnckApplication *app)
{
  g_return_val_if_fail (WNCK_IS_APPLICATION (app), NULL);

  /* FIXME this isn't actually implemented, should be different
   * from regular name
   */

  if (app->priv->name)
    return app->priv->name;
  else
    return FALLBACK_NAME;
}
```

Also, looking at the `gtk_window_set_icon_from_file` [code](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkwindow.c#L4826) I am not even sure whether it is possible to get this path as it is not stored in the pixbuf:

```
gboolean
gtk_window_set_icon_from_file (GtkWindow   *window,
                   const gchar *filename,
                   GError     **err)
{
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = load_pixbuf_verbosely (filename, err);

  if (pixbuf)
    {
      gtk_window_set_icon (window, pixbuf);
      g_object_unref (pixbuf);

      return TRUE;
    }
  else
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to find this path with using the pid of the window or the xid...?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with gtk+. Maybe other GUI frameworks like qt store this path.